# Zend_Search_Lucene_Document_Docx when file has special character does not work

Tags: zend-framework

I am having the problem in zend lucene search of PHP. I have used the class `Zend_Search_Lucene_Document_Docx::loadDocxFile($url);` for creating index for document.
and also have set the utf configuration

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(
  new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Utf8_CaseInsensitive()
);
```

for both creating and searching threw index. for normal fields the special character searching is working fine but the doc containing special character are not being return any result while searching within the doc.

Any advice or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is your docx encoded in UTF-8 ? It's mandatory...

Comment: Thanks, LittleBigDev i will check that and let you know.

Comment: I have checked the doc its encoding is UTF-8 but still its having issue in search not working.